# Update Profile using React native and firebase

Tags: firebase, react-native, redux

I have a problem when I try update my User profile using firebase. If Press "save" everything get saved in the database, But the app crash when it try to navigate back to the profile. If I reload the app I can see my saved input displayed, so something goes wrong when I try to navigate.

The error message I get is:

*undefined is not an object (evaluating 'props.route.params.uid")*

By using following code:

```
  const Save = async () => {
      if (imageChanged) {
          const uri = image;
          const childPath = `profile/${firebase.auth().currentUser.uid}`;

          const response = await fetch(uri);
          const blob = await response.blob();

          const task = firebase
              .storage()
              .ref()
              .child(childPath)
              .put(blob);

          const taskProgress = snapshot => {
              console.log(`transferred: ${snapshot.bytesTransferred}`)
          }

          //Saving the Image
          const taskCompleted = () => {
              task.snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL().then((snapshot) => {

                  firebase.firestore().collection("users")
                      .doc(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid)
                      .update({
                         
                          description,
                          image: snapshot,
                      })
                      .then(() => {
                        props.navigation.goBack()
                      })
              })
          }

          const taskError = snapshot => {
              console.log(snapshot)
          }

          task.on("state_changed", taskProgress, taskError, taskCompleted);

    //Save the data if you just save description
      } else {
          saveData({
              description,
          })
      }
  }

  //Save data navigate back to the profile. 
  const saveData = (data) => {
      firebase.firestore().collection("users")
          .doc(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid)
          .update(data).then(() => {
            props.navigation.push("BackToProfile")
        })
  }
```

So if I add my currentUser UID like this, I get following message:

*"Function CollectionReference.doc() requires it's first argument to be non empty string, but is was: undefined"*

```
  //Save data navigate back to the profile. 
  const saveData = (data) => {
      firebase.firestore().collection("users")
          .doc(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid)
          .update(data).then(() => {
            props.navigation.push("BackToProfile", {uid: currentUser.uid})
        })
  }
```

The CurrentUser I get from my Redux. I display an image by using currentUser like this and it works fine. So I supposed I should do the same if want the UID, or do I thinking wrong?

```
profileImage={currentUser.image}
```

When the navigation is done. Want I update my Profiile image
and description. but now I have to reaload the app.

[image: What I want to change after the navigation is done.]

Comment: can you paste the whole implementation ?

Comment: thanks for answer, I added the whole implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You are just missing a little code, here is the correct one:

```
  //Save data navigate back to the profile. 
  const saveData = (data) => {
      firebase.firestore().collection("users")
          .doc(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid)
          .update(data).then(() => {
          //Here the currentUser.uid is undefined so we need to take uid from firebase.auth().currentUser.uid itself.

            props.navigation.push("BackToProfile", {uid: firebase.auth().currentUser.uid})
        })
  }
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate on what you changed and why, so that your answer is actually helpful?

Comment: you were writing `currentUser.uid` but it is not available it is undefined at that line, so i changed it to `firebase.auth().currentUser.uid`

Comment: If it did help you please mark it right :)

Comment: What I meant was updating the answer itself with this information so it can help everyone who stumbles upon this question.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I added an image and som more info in the question.

Comment: it almost hel me, there is no errors, but the profile still not updated after the navigation.

Comment: can you just check that is component is rendering while you navigate back, we can connect if you want.

Comment: Sorry for a late answer! Yes, that would be nice! but were?

Comment: In this screen `BackToProfile ` use componentDidMount to print some console. That will give the idea about it.